# jcanvas - elements randomly reload on page, and loading is not consistent between elements

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, jcanvas

I am using jcanvas to draw an image, and then display various shapes on top of this image (over 100 shapes).  I am having an issue though - as the canvas image, and canvas shapes seem to load at different times.  The canvas shapes appear, and then anywhere from 0-5 seconds later, the image appears.  Also, the shapes and image randomly reload - they disappear for less than a second and then reappear.

I also have a mouseover event tied to each one of these images - could it be that I just have too many shapes, and too many mouseover events?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Turns out Firefox was sometimes loading the the image I was drawing from cache, and sometimes it was not... causing the image to sporadically re-load.

I displayed the image via html, and drew the image using jcanvas via the html elements' id - this has fixed the issue